# SQL Loader how to insert path with spaces

Tags: arguments, sql-loader

I'm using a command of sql loader but I get an error I think due to the space in the path, I tried to put double quotes (") or single quotes (') but I got Syntax error on command-line:

[image]

Comment: It appears there are single quotes inside the double quotes? Those look like copied single quotes.  Try removing those.

Comment: I tried also with both single quotes and double quotes like in the example. I wrote the quotes manually.